# Building EXE file from a Python File (Not the same ordinary question - Please See)

Tags: python, build

I am trying to build an EXE file from my Python code. I know that "pyinstaller" command can do so, but I have something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qlDwF.png), where 'train.py' is the entry point. I also tried 'pyinstaller' command, but the application runs incorrectly. Please can you suggest a solution? It will be great if you help me.

Comment: how do you call pyinstaller ?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get you. @HadiFarah

Comment: how did you use pyinstaller, as far as I know it's the best tool for this. You might need to add information to your spec file to make it work.

Comment: First I navigate CMD to the train.py file location using "cd". Then I do 'pyinstall train.py'

Comment: @HadiFarah So, can you show me how to use pyinstaller to build the file(making it run correctly)?

Comment: can you post the error you get using pyinstaller ? It helps to solve your problem.

Comment: Do you have extra folders that are required by your program? (Example: a 'templates' folder for a Flask Web App project)

Comment: @jhomr Yes there are extra folders required by my program. Folders in which images will be stored, and read by the program

Comment: With pyinstaller you have to add `--add-data "foldername;foldername"` as an argument for each folder you have to add when running the command line command to make an EXE.

Comment: As in, use that --add-data argument for each folder. Not just all the folders in one argument. So if you have 3 folders, you would have 3 add-data arguments.

Comment: @jhomr Thank you so much! You are the only polite one here :)

Comment: People vote -1 for my post :( this is really rude @jhomr

Comment: It happens, don't let it get to you

Comment: @jhomr Thank you :( One more thing. I have also used modules like cv2, and numpy and etc. How do I include them too? Maybe the problem is this (the modules)

Comment: As far as I know, if you have import statements, that's what pyinstaller uses to include packages in the end. I would recommend using `pyinstaller -D --add-data ...` instead of -F if you are using that.

Comment: @jhomr Thank you so much :)

Comment: Anytime. Best of luck with coding in the future!